# Google OR-Tools: Different cost for same node base on position in route

Tags: python, python-3.x, or-tools

I have a list of costs for each node based on the position of a node in a route. The depot is positioned at 0.

```
costs = [
    {"part": 0, "final": 0},
    {"part": 2, "final": 3},
    {"part": 4, "final": 2},
    {"part": 1, "final": 3},
]
```

It means if node 1 is **part** of a route, it will cost only 2, but if it is the **final** destination, it will cost 3.

So the optimized route should be: `0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 2`, which will cost **part** of 1, **part** of 3, and **final** of 2, total cost is 5.

Currently, I can not find a proper way to set a ***dynamic*** cost for a node based on its position in a route. Any idea is appreciated.

I'm using Python with the Google OR-Tools package.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution, set the cost from every node to the depot equal to the **final** cost, and the cost from every node to each other equal to its **part** cost.

Here is my cost matrix that solves my problem:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[3,0,2,2]
[2,4,0,4]
[3,1,1,0]
```

So a node will cost its **final** price if the next node of the trip is the depot, and **part** price if next node is another node.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

- First you need duplicate each nodes.
- for each duplicate node only allow vehicle end as possible next node.
  note: you can do it multiple way, matrix with cost above vehicle max for each other nodes, tweak the `routing.nextVar(index)` to only allow vehicle end indices and -1 if dropped.
- for each rugular node don't allow vehicle end as next node (i.e. can't be the last one)
- create a Disjunction for the pair node + duplicate node to incentive solver to only visit one
  **OR** make the sum of `routig.ActiveVar(index) + routig.ActiveVar(duplicate_index) <= 1`. (i.e. only one node can be visited)
- for final nodes create a disjunction with a penalty cost of part, i.e.
  if the "final" duplicate node is dropped you add the cost of the part node to the objective.
- for regular nodes create a disjunction with a penalty cost of final, i.e.
  if the "in the route" node is dropped you add the cost of the "part" node.

side note: make `0` (depot) also the end node for each vehicle but with a distance cost `any node -> depot == 0` i.e. while you'll always have the last arc `node -> 0` this one won't participate in the objective cost (and you can filter it out in the display), it just used so vehicle end is alway after the real last node so we can create some constraints etc...

So it should work...
note: I will try to create a gist this weekend if I have time and update this answer with a link to the source code...

UPDATE: here the source: https://gist.github.com/Mizux/bb7245a7e2f3abda417997bc6425cb86

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I found a simple solution that solves my problem

Comment: I also learn a lot from your gist, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Impossible. Callbacks must be stateless. This is by design.

Comment: I just need to modify the cost matrix